# A question about the curvature of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$.and angles.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

In O'Hara's paper "Energy of a Knot", Theorem 1.2 he says

> define $\theta(y)\geq0$ by $\cos(\theta(y))=(f'(y),f'(0))$ where $(\ ,\ )$ denotes the standar inner product of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then for $0\leq y\leq\pi/K$, we have $\theta(y)\leq Ky$.

In that work $f$ is an embedding $f:S^1=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ of class $C^2$ such that $|f'(t)|=1$ $\forall t\in S^1$ and $K$ the maximum of the curvature $|f''(t)|$ I know that $\theta(y)$ is the angle between $f'(y)$ and $f'(0)$ but I cannot see why $\theta(y)\leq Ky$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that $f'(0)=e_1$ (the first standard basis vector). The the unit tangent vector $f'(t)=(\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t))$, and so the curvature $\kappa(t)= \|f''(t)\|=\theta'(t)$. Since $\kappa\le K$, we have $\theta'(t)\le K$, and $\theta(t)\le Kt$ for $t\ge 0$. (The apparent reason they restrict to $t\le \pi/K$ is to use the domain of the $\arccos$ function, but that's really not necessary if you take $\theta$ to be a continuous increasing function on its domain.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question, why we can say that $f'(t)=(\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t))$?

Comment: Think about the unit circle. The unit tangent makes angle $\theta$ with $e_1$.